# How can I print Web scraped Items in Ejs template?

Tags: javascript, express, web-scraping, ejs

I am trying to Web Scraping and my Back-End Code is working clearly. My problem is printing data's to Front-End. I use Ejs template. When I try to print it with foreach method, It prints just last items 3 times. But There are a lot of Scraped Items. How Can I solve this ?

Here is my Back-End Code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const _ = require('lodash');


module.exports.getIndex = (req, res) => {
    const items = {
        names: [],
        min: [],
        max: []
    };
    axios.get('https://www.antalya.bel.tr/BilgiEdin/halden-gunluk-fiyatlar').then(res => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        $('.market-place-item-name .text-dark').each((index, element) => {
            const temp = $(element).text()
            _.update(items, 'names', function () {
                return temp;
            })
        })
        $('.market-place-pricing-wrap .text-dark').each((index, element) => {
            const temp = $(element).text()
            _.update(items, 'min', function () {
                return temp;
            }) 
        })
    })
        .then(() => {
            res.render('home/index.ejs', {
                items: items,

            })
        })
}
```

And Here is my Front-End:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% Object.keys(items).forEach(i => { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= items.names %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= items.min %>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <% }) %>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the image of result which I took:
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AICzJ.png)

Comment: Could you provide a data sample from `axios.get` request? It would be easier to diagnose the problem this way.

Comment: axios.get('https://www.antalya.bel.tr/BilgiEdin/halden-gunluk-fiyatlar').then(res => { console.log(res.data) })     it gives me the html of target website. It works clear. Problem is about printing or using of foreach method.